# While using Intel GPU, Ubuntu 16.04 freezes on shutdown

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, shutdown, intel, freeze

My laptop has **Intel 6700HQ** CPU and **Nvidia 960M** as graphics card. I have **nvidia-361** driver installed.

I can use the nvidia program provided with the driver to switch between Intel GPU and Nvidia GPU. Nvidia GPU works fine actually, and gives me no problems most of the time. But it heats a lot and drains/heats up the battery too. So it is not practical to use.

While switching from nvidia GPU to intel GPU, I'm not having any problems. When nvidia is on, I can easily reboot, suspend, sleep, poweroff. But when I'm on intel GPU, I can do none of those. It always freezes and I have to hold on the power button to force close it. If it sleeps, it won't wake up and so on. Same problem occurs if I use terminal commands (such as `sudo reboot`) to do these too.

It stays like one of these. And nothing happens:
[image: It stays like one of these. And nothing happens.]

The cursor doesn't blink. Screen is completely frozen.

I've removed "quiet splash" from grub to see what's wrong in more details, but it gave something like [image: this, which, doesn't tell much.]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 had a lot of problem with external GPU (nVidia or ATI) and with Intel Power States of 6th generation Intel processors. I have your same problem and installing kernel Linux 4.6 (instead of 4.4) I have solved my problem.

Enter these commands on your terminal (for 64bit PCs):

```
cd /tmp/

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201606100558_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: Hello trunk96, I did what you said and it gave an [error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-361/+bug/1573508) about nvidia. Once the installation was done, I was unable to switch back to nvidia GPU. Reboot, poweroff etc. seemed to work fine though. Then I've removed and reinstalled nvidia-361 driver to realize Ubuntu freezes right after logging in. I'll try to find different nvidia drivers.

Comment: If you can't switch to nVidia GPU you can try to select "Ubuntu with kernel 4.4" in advanced option in GRUB and switch from Intel GPU to nVidia GPU, so you can restart to kernel 4.6. In my case I have no problem with kernel installation. Keep me informed! :)

Comment: I have reinstalled nvidia-361. Rebooted and switched to kernel 4.4. And tried switching to nvidia GPU. But nothing happened. Tried switching to nvidia a couple of times. Doesn't seem to work. It stays on intel GPU. Same happened with other nvidia drivers. Same goes with kernel 4.6, in addition Ubuntu freezes on the desktop while logging out/shutting down. This is really strange. Should I reinstall Ubuntu? And thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes..try to reinstall Ubuntu because I have you same hardware and in my case all work fine after kernel 4.6 installation, so I think that is a software problem

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04, and now I'm back where I've started :) I thought you may want to know: After updating kernel to 4.6, opening "Brightness & Lock" also froze Ubuntu. I don't know if you use "screenfetch" but, it was broken too. Thanks anyway. I hope your answer helps someone else :)